# How to use dblquad for double integration?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython, quad

The following example is provided on `Scipy`'s reference page for `integration`.

```
from scipy import integrate
N = 5
def f(t, x):
   return np.exp(-x*t) / t**N
integrate.nquad(f, [[1, np.inf],[0, np.inf]])
```

The following is the error I get from my `IPython` notebook (on cloud.sagemath.com):
[image]

It is my guess that `cloud.sagemath.com` has not upgraded to the latest version of `Scipy` and therefore it lacks the module for `nquad`. However, all I need is integration over two variables and therefore wanted to use `dblquad` which is already available on the cloud.

Therefore, I modified the last line to suit the `dblquad` syntax as shown below:
[image]

But it still pops up the error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. What is the error in my script? I have pasted the entire error message below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2d0c5cf05694> in <module>()
      4 def f(t, x):
      5     return np.exp(-x*t) / t**N
----> 6 integrate.dblquad(f,1, np.inf,0, np.inf)

/usr/local/sage/sage-6.2.rc0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args, epsabs, epsrel)
    424 
    425     """
--> 426     return quad(_infunc,a,b,(func,gfun,hfun,args),epsabs=epsabs,epsrel=epsrel)
    427 
    428 def _infunc2(y,x,func,qfun,rfun,more_args):

/usr/local/sage/sage-6.2.rc0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    246     if type(args) != type(()): args = (args,)
    247     if (weight is None):
--> 248         retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
    249     else:
    250         retval = _quad_weight(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limlst,limit,maxp1,weight,wvar,wopts)

/usr/local/sage/sage-6.2.rc0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    313             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    314         else:
--> 315             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    316     else:
    317         if infbounds !=0:

/usr/local/sage/sage-6.2.rc0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _infunc(x, func, gfun, hfun, more_args)
    371 
    372 def _infunc(x,func,gfun,hfun,more_args):
--> 373     a = gfun(x)
    374     b = hfun(x)
    375     myargs = (x,) + more_args

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

**Edit 1:** I made a working script using the inputs from the users `Weckesser` and `Chen`. Just for the sake of completeness for anyone stumbling upon this question in the future.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
N=5
def f(t, x):
    return np.exp(-x*t) / t**N
R1=integrate.dblquad(f,0, np.inf,lambda x: 1, lambda x: np.inf)
print R1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reread the [docstring for `dblquad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html).  The fourth and fifth arguments must be callable (i.e. functions).  You have passed in `0` and `np.inf`.  The functions are the lower and upper bounds of the inner integral.

There is [an example in the tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#general-multiple-integration-dblquad-tplquad-nquad).

Answer (score 5):

The signature of dblquad is

```
integrate.dblquad(func, a, b, gfun, hfun, args=(), epsabs=1.49e-08, epsrel=1.49e-08)
```

**gfun : callable**

The lower boundary curve in y which is a function taking a single
floating point argument (x) and returning a floating point result: a
lambda function can be useful here.

**hfun : callable**

The upper boundary curve in y (same requirements as `gfun`).

So you need to replace gfun and hfun to functions.